# About algorithm package

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I'm making an algorithm figure using `\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, longend]{algorithm2e}` and `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \KwResult{Best solution found for distribution}
    Population  initialization

    \For{population size}{
        execute phases\Comment{Mutation and crossover}
        
        \If{elitism}{ 
            $population[0] = fittest$ \Comment{Next evolution}
         }
    }
    \KwRet{$fittest$}
    \caption{Genetic algorithm}\label{alg:genetic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and I'd like to add two details:

1. Add a *Require* tag. I tried to add it using `\Require` but it doesn't work. Do I need another package additionally? Something like:

[image]

2. Change the style of the number lines, similar to these ones:

[image]

I appreciate any help/info. Thanks!

Comment: As always on the site,. please extend your sniplet so a full but minimal example which others can copy and test as is. Then it is a lot easier to help.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've uploaded an example completely.

Comment: `\SetNlSty{}{}{:}` should adjust the line numbers according to the image you added.

Comment: @leandriis worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix the use of algorithm packages like [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (which provides `algpseudocode`). You should stick to one. In your case it seems like `algorithm2e` provides the functionality that you're interested in, so build on that.

The minimal example provides `\KwRequire` and a new `\Comment`, together with the appropriate line number formatting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,lined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

% Set algorithm keyword formatting
\newcommand{\Var}{\textup}
\newcommand{\Comment}{\tcc*[r]}
\SetKwComment{tcc}{$\triangleright$~}{}
\SetCommentSty{normalfont}
\SetKwInput{KwRequire}{Require}
% Set algorithm line numbers
\SetNlSty{}{}{:}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwRequire{Some data input}
  \KwResult{Best solution found for distribution}
  Population initialization\;
  \For{population size}{%
    execute phases \Comment{Mutation and crossover}
    \If{elitism}{%
      $\Var{population[0]} = \Var{fittest}$ \Comment{Next evolution}
    }
  }
  \KwRet{$\Var{fittest}$}
  \caption{Genetic algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```